# If I have one thread writing and many reading, how can I only lock when writing, but not reading?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, caching, pthreads

So I have this structure to a cache I'm writing:

```
struct scache {
        char* rp;
        int ce;
        char* code;
        struct headers* headers;
        struct body* body;
};

struct dcache {
        unsigned char md5[16];
        struct scache scache;
};

struct cache {
        struct scache** scaches;
        size_t scache_size;
        struct dcache** dcaches;
        size_t dcache_size;
};

struct scache* getSCache(struct cache* cache, char* rp, int ce);

struct dcache* getDCache(struct cache* cache, char* rp, int ce, unsigned char* md5);

int addSCache(struct cache* cache, struct scache* scache);

int addDCache(struct cache* cache, struct dcache* dcache);
```

I want to use mutexes so that I can not allow any reading when I'm writing, but not have reads block other reads. So reading threads do not block each other, but if one adds one, it'll block other writes and reads.

I looked into mutexes, but I can't wrap my mind around how to implement this right. I think I could just lock the writing, but then what if a read see's the size larger or smaller than it really is, then under reads or over reads, both causing issues with double caching or memory corruption.

Comment: You could use `_Atomic` and `stdatomic.h` (since C11). Much more lightweight than mutexes, etc., but may be more complex to implement, depending on the actual data types.

Comment: Note that reads also have to be atomic. That might very well require locking against intermediate writes. Not to talk about other issues like instruction/memory access reordering by the compiler and/or hardware.

Comment: @Olaf Atomicity and read-write locking are two completely different concepts. Proper implementation of a read-write lock will use atomic operations if available.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I did not say they are the same, but they may be related, While modern CPUs provide atomic reads/writes for the base-types, they need more for compound data types. And there are alternatives to locking, like exclusive access with hardware-supportede change-detection like ARMs LDREX/STREX instructions. However, sometime a lock is more efficient than retries. All depends on the actual usage, e.g. frequency of accesses. Note that there is atomic accesses on two levels actually. Hardware/low leve and more complex structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a read-write lock. There are different implementation depending on which way they are biased.

The two border extremes are:

- writes get immediate access
- writes get access only if there 0 reads waiting

Most implementations are somewhere in the middle biased towards writes or reads.

For a standard POSIX implementation see: `pthread_rwlock_t`   http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_init.html